# Query funciona no banco de dados mas não via código

Tags: c#, oracle, query

```
using (var cnx = new OleDbConnection(new AdministradorDAO().conexao))
            {
                var sql =
            @"insert into usuarios(matricula, nome, senha, nivel, maleta, email) 
            values (@matricula, @nome, @senha, @nivel, @maleta, @email)";


                using (var cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, cnx))
                {
                    cnx.Open();

                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@matricula", txt_matricula.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nome", txt_nome.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@senha", txt_senha.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nivel", DropDownList_nivel.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@maleta", txt_maleta.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", txt_email.Text);

                    try { cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); }
                    catch { }
                    finally { if (cnx.State == ConnectionState.Open) cnx.Close(); }
                }
            }
```

Ao fazer o insert diretamente no banco, roda perfeitamente

```
insert into actweb.usuarios (matricula, nome, senha, nivel, maleta, email) values ('TESTE', 'Frederico', 'TESTE', 1, 7000, 'daerror@error.com.br');
```

Eu executando diretamente, sem usar os parameters da certo.

> var sql = @"insert into usuarios(id,nome) values (ID_USUARIOS.nextval, 'Vai dar certo')";

Comment: insert into actweb.usuarios (matricula, nome, senha, nivel, maleta, email) values ('TESTE', 'Frederico', 'TESTE', 1, 7000, 'daerror@error.com.br');
Ao fazer o insert diretamente no banco, roda perfeitamente

Comment: Você deve [edit] sua pergunta para adicionar esta informação. Você sabe que este `try catch finnaly` não tem utilidade alguma no seu código? Até está causando problema. O `using` está resolvendo o fechamento da conexão.

Comment: O `catch` está engolindo o erro. Se você tirar ele, você terá alguma informação útil para descobri onde está o erro. Aí você poderá resolver ou poderá postar aqui qual é o erro, assim fica mais fácil ajudar você.

Comment: Tirei o catch, agora está apresentando este erro
Ocorreram um ou mais erros durante o processamento do comando.
ORA-00936: expressão não encontrada

Comment: Você precisa [editar] sua pergunta para deixar ela completa com esta informação e facilitar para quem conhece os erros do Oracle e pode lhe ajudar.

Answer (score 4):

Tem duas coisas erradas no seu código:

- `try` com `catch` vazio;
- Que eu me lembre, a sintaxe para inserção em Oracle não começa por `@`, e sim por dois-pontos;

O correto seria algo assim:

```
using (var cnx = new OleDbConnection(new AdministradorDAO().conexao))
{
    var sql =
        @"insert into usuarios(matricula, nome, senha, nivel, maleta, email) 
        values (:matricula, :nome, :senha, :nivel, :maleta, :email)";

    using (var cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, cnx))
    {
        cnx.Open();

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("matricula", txt_matricula.Text != "" ? txt_matricula.Text : DbValue.Null);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("nome", txt_nome.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("senha", txt_senha.Text != "" ? txt_senha.Text : DbValue.Null);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("nivel", DropDownList_nivel.Text != "" ? DropDownList_nivel.Text : DbValue.Null);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("maleta", txt_maleta.Text != "" txt_maleta.Text : DbValue.Null);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("email", txt_email.Text != "" ? txt_email.Text : DbValue.Null);

        try 
        { 
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
        }
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            throw; 
        }
        finally 
        { 
            if (cnx.State == ConnectionState.Open) cnx.Close(); 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: colocando os dois-pontos, exibe a seguinte mensagem: ORA-01008: nem todas as variáveis são limitadas. Olhei o significado e fala que ocorre quando algum dos parâmetros não foi informado.Porém no meu código não tem nenhum parâmetro que não foi informado.

Comment: Não encontro a solução para o meu problema !

Comment: Bom, esse erro novo indica que alguma coisa está indo nula, o que não pode. Sabe me dizer qual campo é?

Comment: no meu teste estou passando todos os campos, mais o único campos obrigatório é ID, e NOME. Porém o ID é auto-incremento.

Comment: @Frederico Então tá errado. Você tem que dizer quando é nulo. Vou editar a resposta.

Comment: acrescentando o DbValue, da esta mensagem: The name 'DbValue' does not exist in the current context

Comment: tem alguma sugestão que você possa me dar? Lembrando que meu banco de dados é um oracle 10g

Comment: Você adicinou corretamente a referência de `DbValue`, como descrito aqui? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dbnull.value(v=vs.110).aspx